# multiply two functions with each other (matlab)

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to multiply two functions with each other and plot the result. but I got an empty figure!
the both functions work fine if I plot each one like this:

```
  plot(x,ramp3(x))
  hold on
  plot(x,unitStep(3-x))
```

this is my code:

```
  clear all
  clc

  x=0:0.001:20;
  y3=@(x) ramp3(x).*unitStep(3-x);

  plot(x,y3)
  axis([-4 4 -2 2])
```

Comment: Are you intentionally creating an anonymous function there, or just trying to multiply the results of `ramp3(x)` and `unitStep(3-x)` for the `x` you initialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `@(...) ...` syntax, MATLAB generates an anonymous function, treating the argument list within the parentheses as inputs. The scope of those variables is limited to the anonymous function. The function is not evaluated until you call it and pass in valid inputs.

In your case `y3` is a function handle. You need to use something like `plot(x,y3(x))` to actually evaluate the function `y3` at the points in your array `x`.